# How can I group / window date ordered events delineated by an arbitrary expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I would like to group some data together based on dates and some (potentially arbitrary) indicator:

```
Date       | Ind
================
2016-01-02 | 1
2016-01-03 | 5
2016-03-02 | 10
2016-03-05 | 15
2016-05-10 | 6
2016-05-11 | 2
```

I would like to group together subsequent (date-ordered) rows but breaking the group after `Indicator >= 10`:

```
Date       | Ind | Group
========================
2016-01-02 | 1   |   1
2016-01-03 | 5   |   1
2016-03-02 | 10  |   1

2016-03-05 | 15  |   2

2016-05-10 | 6   |   3
2016-05-11 | 2   |   3
```

I did find a promising technique at the end of a blog post: "[Use this Neat Window Function Trick to Calculate Time Differences in a Time Series](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/12/use-this-neat-window-function-trick-to-calculate-time-differences-in-a-time-series/)" (the final subsection, "Extra Bonus"), but the important part of the query uses a keyword (`FILTER`) that doesn't seem to be supported in SQL Server (and a quick Google later and I'm not sure where it is supported!).

I'm still hopeful a technique using a window function might be the answer. I just need a counter that I can add to every row, (like `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` does) but that only increments when some arbitrary condition evaluates as `true`. Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: what is the indicator and how is it calculated?

Comment: This isn't real data (I know, I know). In actual fact, I'm calculating the gap between subsequent dates using `LEAD()` and I want to delineate groups when the gap is larger than a particular value (30 days, say). For reasons of intellectual curiosity / future flexibility, I'm hoping for an answer that works in the general case (i.e. where "Indicator" can be any arbitrary true / false expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Date] DATETIME, Ind INT)

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES
('2016-01-02', 1),
('2016-01-03', 5),
('2016-03-02', 10),
('2016-03-05', 15),
('2016-05-10', 6),
('2016-05-11', 2)

SELECT [Date],
       Ind,
       1 + SUM([Group]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Group]
FROM 
(
    SELECT  *, 
            CASE WHEN LAG(ind) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) >= 10 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS [Group] 
      FROM @t
) t
```

Just mark row as `1` when previous is greater than `10` else `0`. Then a running sum will give you the desired result.

Comment: Shouldn't have spent so much time formatting my answer..  well here's almost the same with also date difference check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/162ab/1

Comment: @JamesZ, almost the same :)

Comment: I liked your answer a lot so I edited it with easier to read formatting (for me, at least).  I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Thank you! Very neat, much more straightforward than I feared (almost embarrassingly so, in fact) and even incorporating my example numbering system and poorly chosen column names :)

Answer (score 1):

Giving full credit to Giorgi for the idea, but I've modified his answer (both for my benefit and for future readers).

Just change the `CASE` statement to see if 30 or more days have lapsed since the last record:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Date] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES
('2016-01-02'),
('2016-01-03'),
('2016-03-02'),
('2016-03-05'),
('2016-05-10'),
('2016-05-11')

SELECT [Date],
       1 + SUM([Group]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Group]
FROM 
(
    SELECT  [Date], 
            CASE WHEN DATEADD(d, -30, [Date]) >= LAG([Date]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date])
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END AS [Group] 
      FROM @t
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for concentrating on my actual requirements:upvote for you. Obviously Giorgi answered the question as posed and (as acknowledged) inspired your answer.